# Merge two rows in a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am very new to Python and I am trying to do a very simple merge of every two lines in a csv file. Basically I want it like this:

Input:

```
[H1],1,2,3,4
[H2],5,6,7,8
[H1],a,b,c,d
[H2],e,f,g,h
```

Output:

```
[H1],1,2,3,4,[H2],5,6,7,8
[H1],a,b,c,d,[H2],e,f,g,h
```

This is a brief example, but the csv file has up to 167 columns with the two lines combined. This is what I have:

```
import csv
f = open("sample.csv",'rU').read().split("\n")
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    if row[0].startswith("[H1]"): 
        i=[]
        while i<167: n = row.append([",".join(row[i]+row[i+1])])
        print n
```

However when I run it I get the following error:

```
    print n
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `row.append` does not return anything. What is `n` supposed to be? If `i = []`, what is `while i < 167` supposed to mean?

Comment: You are comparing a list (`i`) with a number (`167`).  So that `while` loop either never runs → no defining of `n`, or will be an endless loop.

Comment: I am trying to save the concatenated row into 'n'. For i=[], that was a mistake, I just want it to loop through 167 times.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

f = open("sample.csv",'rU').read().split("\n")
reader = csv.reader(f)

i = 0

for row in reader:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        line = row
    else:
        line = line + row
        print ", ".join(line)

    i += 1
```

Comment: First line number is even, second odd (i). You need even number of lines in the CSV file to make it work for all pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Input `i.csv`:

```
1,2,3
foo,bar,baz
4,5,6
qux,quux.quuux
```

Python codce:

```
with open("i.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    i = 0
    for row in reader:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            newRow = row
        else:
            newRow = newRow + row
            print(newRow)
        i = i + 1
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
['4', '5', '6', 'qux', 'quux', 'quuux']
```

Comment: Not binding the open file to a name makes it impossible to close it after it's not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `while i<167: n = row.append([",".join(row[i]+row[i+1])])` is like writing:

```
while i<167:
    n = row.append([",".join(row[i]+row[i+1])])
```

So the scope of `n` is the loop block. Your `print n` is out of that scope thus raising `NameError`.

You could add `n = None` right before the `while`:

```
n = None
while i<167: n = row.append([",".join(row[i]+row[i+1])])
print n
```

Or move `print n` into the loop block:

```
while i<167:
    n = row.append([",".join(row[i]+row[i+1])])
    print n
```

Note that any of these changes will avoid your program interruption by the out of scope error but you will print a lot of lines containing `None` because `append` returns `None`: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: What does `row.append` return?

Comment: @Tichodroma It returns `None`, so it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Tichodroma It returns `None` but that is not the origin of the exception. Just another problem with the OP code.

Comment: @BlackJack Right, that's why I am asking.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo So your answer removes the scope problem but still the OP doesn't have a working solution. Of course, that's because we don't know waht the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to combine the line pairs:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip


def main():
    with open('sample.csv', 'rb') as input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)
        for even_row, odd_row in izip(reader, reader):
            combined_row = even_row + odd_row
            print combined_row


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```